# accessing function on stage from a child

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function in stage and need to call it from a child I do I do it...

```
// In main stage
var child_mc:mcChild = new mcChild();
addChild(child_mc);


function parentFunction():void
{
   trace("Do something here");
}


// inside mcChild

button_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, callParentFunction);

function callParentFunction(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  // here I need to call the function that is in the main stage.
  // I tried 
  // parent.parentFunction(); 
  // and
  // root.parentFunction(); but nothing works...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
child_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onParentFunction)

onParentFunction(e:MouseEvent)
{
  parentFunction();
}
```

Whenever you need to call a function on a parent class then use events. If you were not clicking on a child you can do something similar by dispatching an event. Simply:

In **child_MC**

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("SOME_EVENT"));
```

**Parent**

```
child_mc.addEventListener("SOME_EVENT",onSomeEvent);

function onSomeEvent(e:Event):void
{

}
```

Comment: fixed a little mistake I made in my second example

Answer (score -1):

**here :**

```
// stage movie
MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(0)).someFunction();
```